# Fetching data from API that requires If-modified-since, using request.js in node,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-304

I'm making a proxy to the [4chan API.](https://github.com/4chan/4chan-API) I'm using [request.js](https://github.com/mikeal/request) in Node.js + Express to make the queries to the API and I don't know how exactly implement the "If-modified-since" that the API requires, this is the code:

```
app.get('/api/boards', function(request, response){
    req({uri:'https://api.4chan.org/boards.json', json: true}, function (error, res, data) {
        if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            response.jsonp(data['boards']);
        }
    });
});
```

If I make a query to 4chan that already has been done it doesn't answer and the timeout fires.

4chan API rules:

> - Do not make more than one request per second.
> - Thread updating should be set to a minimum of 10 seconds, preferably higher.
> - Use If-Modified-Since when doing your requests.
> - Make API requests using the same protocol as the app. Only use SSL when a user is accessing your app over HTTPS.
> - More to come later...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request module allows you to pass request headers into the options, so you can do this:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  uri: 'https://api.4chan.org/boards.json',
  json: true,
  headers: {'If-Modified-Since': 'Sun, 06 Oct 2013 01:16:45 GMT'}
};

request(options, function (error, res, data) {
  // other processing
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Another question, now I added the header and the API responds always, not blocking me the access but because is with a 304 code no new data arrives and I send nothing in the http response. How I can make a 200 connection save the data and then when I get a 304 respond with that data. How will be the correct way to implement this?

Comment: There's multiple ways to do this - if there isn't too much data, then you can store the data into a variable. Otherwise, you could write the data into a file and access it later.